# PhantomJS multiple log files and log rotating

Tags: node.js, logging, phantomjs, headless-browser, winston

I need help with logging functions in PhantomJS. I want to render canvas images on the server side with PhantomJS. This part runs very well, but I can't figure out how to setup a good logging function in Phantom.

I want to separete logs due to their level in separtet files.

```
logger.log('info', 'Test Info Message'); // -> info.log
logger.log('error', 'Log Exception'); // -> error.log
```

Is there another way as piping the process output to some file?

I would like to use some NodeJS logging framework as [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) directly in the PhantomJS because with winston I could use log ratation out of the box.

Thx for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Winston uses node.js' file streams from the [fs module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html). PhantomJS also has a [fs module](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/), but it has a completely different API. That's why you can't use Winston for that directly. You could potentially rewrite Winston so that it runs in PhantomJS.